# What tool can I use to label images with True/False?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, label, tooling

I have a collection of images, ~10.000. Every image is taken from the same place, with or without birds. I want to label the collection -> True (there is a bird), False (there are no birds)

Is it any tool to do it fast and efficiently, without manually handling a sheet with file names and labels?

Comment: irfanView F7 and keys 7/8 to move to subfolder TRUE/FALSE. Maybe you can even parametrize shortcuts for each of them

Comment: If there already was a tool that does that for you, what would you need machine-learning for? you could just use the tool instead of training your own model, since you trust the output of that tool anyways.

Comment: I am preparing a training set. If I am going to label 10K images I'd want to do it fast, with minimal toil.